# Discrepancy in simple date format between Android 4.3 and Android 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am using the following pattern for my `SimpleDateFormat` object - `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ`. According to the [official Android  documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) this the timezone format I am using `ZZZZZ` is supposed to format the input date and return a string that has the timezone info in the format `sign HH:mm` (eg. -08:00). This works in Andriod 4.3 but unfortunately the same code returns the timezone info in the format `sign HHmm` (eg. -0800). Please note the missing colon. Anyone knows the reason for this?!

Comment: If you can reduce this to a simple reproducible test case you should file a bug.

Comment: I am with @caskey on this one. If it isn't a bug then there should at least be something in documentation regarding the change (and why).

Comment: great!! i will cross check it tonight and file a bug if it is really one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is stated in the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) itself

```
Five-count patterns (such as "MMMMM") used for the shortest non-numeric 
representation of a field were introduced in Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean MR2, 
API level 18).
```

Figured it out from the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73209) filed for this

Comment: @DanielOchoa - the best would be to use https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android